# Creating an addon to override cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies, xul

I'm working on writing a plugin to change the value of a cookie to prevent log out. I was planning to have it so that on every page load the value of that cookies is changed to my value. Is this the best way to go at it? Is it safe? I'm mostly needing to know how other developers would go at it and what are the pit falls of my current idea.

Bascially, all I'd need to do is change the cookie's value if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a massive 'it depends on the site in question' answer...

Normal the session ID cookie in the browser links to a session ID known by the server.

If the site in question has an 'autologout after time x of inactivity', it is most likely the server that is deleting it's session ID after that timeout, so changing the cookie on the client will have no effect.

Comment: Well all I'd need to do is change the cookie's value if it exists.

Comment: Whatever value I want...? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

On windows you could use the Fiddler HTTP debugger to do this. You can set up rules to apply modifications to the HTTP requests and responses.